# How can I show that traverse interacts sensibly with fmap?

Tags: haskell, traversal

It seems intuitively obvious that the following law should hold:

```
traverse f . fmap g = traverse (f . g)
```

The only `Traversable` law that *seems* to apply directly is

```
fmap g = runIdentity . traverse (Identity . g)
```

That changes the problem to

```
traverse f . runIdentity . traverse (Identity . g)
```

The only law that seems to have vaguely the right shape to apply to this is the naturality law. That, however, is about applicative transformations, and I don't see any of those around.

Unless I'm missing something, the only thing left is a parametricity proof, and I've not yet gotten a clue about how to write those.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Note that this proof isn't actually necessary, as the result in question is indeed a free theorem. See [Reid Barton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32813063/2751851).*

I believe this will do:

```
traverse f . fmap g -- LHS
```

By the `fmap/traverse` law,

```
traverse f . runIdentity . traverse (Identity . g)
```

Since `fmap` for `Identity` is effectively `id`,

```
runIdentity . fmap (traverse f) . traverse (Identity . g)
```

The `Compose` law offers a way to collapse two traversals into one, but we must first introduce `Compose` using `getCompose . Compose = id`.

```
runIdentity . getCompose . Compose . fmap (traverse f) . traverse (Identity . g)
-- Composition law:
runIdentity . getCompose . traverse (Compose . fmap f . Identity . g)
```

Again using the `Identity` `fmap`,

```
runIdentity . getCompose . traverse (Compose . Identity . f . g)
```

`Compose . Identity` is an applicative transformation, so by naturality,

```
runIdentity . getCompose . Compose . Identity . traverse (f . g)
```

Collapsing inverses,

```
traverse (f . g) -- RHS
```

Invoked laws and corollaries, for the sake of completeness:

```
-- Composition:
traverse (Compose . fmap g . f) = Compose . fmap (traverse g) . traverse f
-- Naturality:
t . traverse f = traverse (t . f) -- for every applicative transformation t
-- `fmap` as traversal:
fmap g = runIdentity . traverse (Identity . g)
```

The latter fact follows from the identity law, `traverse Identity = Identity`, plus the uniqueness of `fmap`.

Comment: That's quite impressive. How did you come up with that `getCompose . Compose` trick?

Comment: I suggest submitting this proof for inclusion in the documentation for `Data.Traversable`.

Comment: @dfeuer It was the quickest way to get a `Compose` in the right place to apply the composition law. That step might even be suppressed if we apply `getCompose` to both sides of the composition law before using it, as the `Control.Lens.Traversal` documentation does.

Comment: What exactly is an applicative transformation? `t` is used at (seemingly) two different types in "Naturality" so I assume it has some higher-rank type or using some typeclasses?

Comment: @user2407038, it's only used at one type. If `f` and `g` are applicative functors, an applicative transformation from `f` to `g` is a polymorphic function `t::f a -> g a` such that `t . pure = pure` (`pure` used there with two types) and `t (x <*> y) = t x <*> t y` always (`<*>` used at two types).

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure it has to be polymorphic.

Comment: @dfeuer It has to, as it wouldn't be a natural transformation otherwise. The polymorphism ensures it can't modify the `a` values.

Comment: Why would that be a problem?

Comment: @dfeuer A natural transformation between Haskell `Functor`s preserves functions being `fmap`ped, so that `t . fmap f = fmap f . t` for any `f` (incidentally, that also follows from the two properties of applicative transformations). There is no way that can hold if `t` can change the values within the `Functor`. (Back when I was trying to grok natural transformations I wrote [some notes on this topic](https://duplode.github.io/posts/what-does-fmap-preserve.html). You might find them, or the links therein, useful, even though there is nothing specific about `Applicative` there.)

Comment: I guess I'm still wondering whether it's possible for a `Traversable` instance to obey the naturality law for all natural applicative transformations but not all unnatural applicative transformations. Also whether there are any implications between naturality and those applicative transformation laws I'm not seeing.

Comment: @dfeuer An unnatural applicative transformation isn't an applicative transformation in this sense, both by definition (though right now I can't recall a reference to back up that claim) and because, for an applicative transformation `t`, `t (x <*> y) = t x <*> t y` => `t (pure f <*> y) = t (pure f) <*> t y` <=> `t (pure f <*> y) = pure f <*> t y` <=> `t (fmap f y) = fmap f (t y)` (that is, naturality).

Comment: Those are some very nice notes on your blog. Thanks.

Comment: @dfeuer By the way, thank you for decompressing the proof through that edit :)

Answer (score 4):

According to lambdabot it is a free theorem (parametricity).

In response to `@free traverse :: (a -> F b) -> T a -> F (T b)`, lamdabot produces

```
$map_F g . h = k . f => $map_F ($map_T g) . traverse h = traverse k . $map_T f
```

Set `g = id` so that `h = k . f`. Then the conclusion becomes

```
traverse (k . f) = traverse k . fmap f
```

Comment: What do `F` and `T` mean to @free?

Comment: Nothing, they are arbitrary type constructors (maybe they need to be functors for `$map_F` to make sense, but the `f` and `t` in the type of `traverse` are functors anyway).

Comment: Do the capital letters mean that they represent specific types rather than type variables?

Comment: Yes. `traverse` is only assumed to be parametrically polymorphic in `a` and `b`. (In fact it is polymorphic to some degree in `f` as well, though lambdabot doesn't know how to take that into account (nor do I).)

Comment: For example, the free theorem for `fun :: a -> a` is `f . fun = fun . f`, while the free theorem for `fun :: A -> A` is just the tautology `fun = fun`.

Comment: That's really neat, since it means the law I desire doesn't depend on any of the `Traversable` laws at all, and applies even to functor-specific `traverse`-like functions. Unfortunately, the mathematical machinery behind these free theorems is pretty intense.

Comment: Looking back at this answer, it is worth noting that this being is a free theorem seems to be a quite significant. If we make `k = id` in the above, we get `traverse f = traverse id . fmap f`. If we define `sequenceA = traverse id`, that means the fact that `traverse` can be decomposed into `fmap` and `sequenceA` is independent of the `Traversable` laws.